# saving in NSDocumentDirectory causing crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app, from the `camera roll` I picked (single/multiple images). Then I'm saving those images in `NSDocumentDirectory`, Here is my code for that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [info objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]];

            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

            NSLog(@"saving at:%@",savedImagePath);           
 }
```

From that, it is working normally. But when I return again in the camera roll then save again (WITHOUT restaring the app) it sometimes crashes(most of the time) when testing in the actual device or lags the app. I dunno if its the `AGImagePicker` library which I'm using for importing the photo or my way of saving it. Is my way of saving in `NSDocumentDirectory` wrong? Or if there is better way help would be much appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you tried running by enabling zombie option ?

Comment: That is what I haven't tried.

Comment: Why do not you set the exception breakpoint?

Comment: When running in simulator, its okay. But when in actual device, this were the time mostly it crashes.

Comment: Paste your device error logs here..

Comment: I was talking about device error log.. Just connect your device with iTunes and get from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Zombie object and run

[image]